# How can I avoid using default export when exporting a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a the following component as a function:

```
function Modal(props) {}
```

I export it this way:

```
export default Modal;
```

However, I want to export it form its index.js file in this way:

```
export { Modal } from "./Modal";
```

But, I get an error... does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also export it like this

```
export function Model(props) {}
```

and import it like this

```
import {Model} from './Model';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
export { default as Modal } from "./Modal";
```

Comment: If I try that I get this error: './Modal' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Modal')

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to import a default exported component as a named exported one.

```
import Modal from './Modal'; // that's how we import a "default exported" component
import { Modal } from './Modal' // that's how we import a "named exported" component
```

To achieve what you want, you could either change the export of your main component to be a named export. Or you could import it like that in your `index.js` file:

```
import Modal from './Modal';

export { Modal };
```